# Make a php script for each query needed

Tags: mysql, database

I'm making an application that registers some users as well as logging in, retrieving information from the database to display to the user.

And I'm using MySQL database with `php` script to execute the queries needed.

My question is that do I have to make a `php` script for every query I need?
for example I make a `php` script for logging in only called `login.php`, and `register.php` ?

Comment: No. You can do it however you like. Maybe consider using a framework which will help you structure your application code, if you haven't got any experience of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question.

I think you'll be okay with login.php for login proccess, register.php for user registration process. If you'd like to show up user profile you can add profile.php and maybe update-profile.php for your users so they can update their profile later.

However, it's also depend on your coding skills and experience to make a decision on how many php files do you need for all of your queries.

I hope my answer is okay for you.